# Meteor update a Collection object

Tags: meteor

in Meteor, I'm having a collection with a Schema, and a number of items are added dynamically.

In this case, I'm dealing with *milestones object*, and once the user check one off I want to update complete in this Collections item to true (default is false)

Here is my schema

```
milestones: {
type: Array,
optional: true
},
'milestones.$': {
type: Object
},
'milestones.$.name': {
type: String
},
'milestones.$.hours': {
type: Number
},
'milestones.$.complete': {
type: Boolean
}
```

How do I write a `$set` statement for this?

Comment: `Milestones.update({_id:this._id},{$set:{'milestone.complete':true}})` supposing you are using an event handler and you can use the `this._id` context.

Comment: Only Milestones is not a collection, it's an object in Projects collection. I was trying this  `Projects.update({_id:currentPostId, 'milestones.name':this.name}, {$set:{completed:true}});` but to no avail..

Comment: why do you need the name? just do a  `Projects.update({_id:currentPostId},{$set:{'milestones.complete':true}})`

Comment: I need to identify the milestone, as there is more than one in the same object.

Comment: `Projects.update({_id:this._id},milestones:{$elemMatch:{'milestones.name':this.name}}, {$set: {'milestones.$.complete':true}});` try with that

Comment: Ethaan, the code above throws 'Unexpected token :' after `Projects.update({_id:this._id},milestones`

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of objects so, [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) do the trick here.

```
Projects.update({_id:this._id},{milestones:{$elemMatch:{'milestones.$‌​.name':this.name}},{$set:{'milestone.$.complete':value}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Aldeed I found a solution - which needs to be called on server side, otherwise it won't let the update happen. Do:

```
Projects.update({_id:currentPostId, 'milestones.name':name}, {$set:{'milestones.$.complete':true}});
```

The function is called on the client with Meteor.call with all needed params.

Answer (score -1):

According to your schema you have an object containing an array of objects. So you should write you `$set` like this:

```
{$set: {'milestone.$.complete':value}}
```

This will update the first array element corresponding to the query.

You can find [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) the official documentation if you want to know more about arrays updates in Mongo.